# WCF ASynchronous calls within a Windows forms Application using a timer

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, asynchronous

I am new to developing with Windows forms applications and I have an issue I could do with some help / guidance on the best practice approach I should be taking.

Background:

I have an forms based application that needs to refresh every minute with data from a WCF service and then update the UI with the latest results in a List View control. I have this all working in principal but the application crashes intermittently and I need to resolve this. I have stripped out the main parts of the code below. The actual nuts and bolts are probably not required.

Code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
readonly MatchServiceReference.MatchServiceClient _client = new MatchServiceReference.MatchServiceClient();

public Form1()
    {
        _client.GetMMDataCompleted += new EventHandler<GetMMDataCompletedEventArgs>(_client_GetMMDataCompleted);
    }    

//Arm Timer
private void ArmTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        aTimer = new Timer();

        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;

        aTimer.Interval = 60000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

//Timer elapsed event
 private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            LoadMatches();

            if (LastUpdated.InvokeRequired)
            {
                LastUpdated.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { LastUpdated.Text = e.SignalTime.ToString(); }));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

        }

    }

//Load matches
private void LoadMatches()
    {
        try
        {
            aTimer.Enabled = false;
            _client.GetMMDataAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //EventLog.WriteEntry("Application", e.InnerException.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

void _client_GetMMDataCompleted(object sender, GetMMDataCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result != null)
        {

            var matches = e.Result;

            Debug.WriteLine("Matches received from service");

            if (!IsHandleCreated && !IsDisposed) return;

            // Invoke an anonymous method on the thread of the form.
            Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
                                       {
                                           try
                                           {
                                               LoadTheMonitorMatches(matches);
                                           }
                                           catch (Exception exception)
                                           {
                                               Debug.WriteLine("INNER EXCEPTION" + exception.InnerException);
                                               Debug.WriteLine("EXCEPTION MESSAGE" + exception.Message);
                                           }
                                       });
        }
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

}

Exception:

The exception I am getting is as follows -

> Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
>   Stack:
>      at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
>      at MM.MatchServiceReference.GetMMDataCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()
>      at MM.Form1._client_GetMMDataCompleted(System.Object, MM.MatchServiceReference.GetMMDataCompletedEventArgs)
>      at MM.MatchServiceReference.MatchServiceClient.OnGetMMDataCompleted(System.Object)
>      at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>      at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>      at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
>      at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

Any help / advice with this would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
  if (e.Result != null)
```

is actually calling the getter for result. Since the event args derive from AsyncCompletedEventArgs this can raise an error if the operation was cancelled or errored. Check the cancelled and error properties first before testing the result and you should be able to trap the problem.

From the docs:
`If the component's asynchronous worker code assigns an exception to the Error property or sets the Cancelled property to true, the property will raise an exception if a client tries to read its value.`

Comment: Thank you for this. I should have spotted this and could indeed be what is causing the problem, I will test it out and report back. Cheers again.

Comment: Thanks a million, this has solved the crashing problem. Your advice is much appreciated on this.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong timer. The `System.Timers.Timer` is intended to use on servers. For a Winform application you should use the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` and add it as a control to your form. When you use it, the UI is responsive between timer ticks but when it goes to bring data, the UI will become irresponsive. If it is not good enough for you, you should use the `BackgroundWorker`.

If the problem is still there after using these components, ask the question again.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will try this out today and get back with results.

Comment: I tried the answer below first as I suspected this would solve the crashing issue, however I will also now be changing my timer as per your advice. Many thanks for this.